# How to change the cursor to Hand in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, cursor

I am using the following Hyperlink Text by using the TextBlock....

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Foreground="#FF057BC3" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight">
     <TextBlock Width="400" Margin="-28 -1 0 0" >
          <Underline>Cursor should be Hand when hits me....</Underline>
     </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Is there any way to change Cursor to Hand when Mouse over in the TextBlock?

Comment: Are you sure that windows-phone-7 tag is correct?

Comment: I am not sure lukas, I am new to Windows-Phone7

Comment: WP7 is an OS without mouse, you can only use touch. Do you want to show a hand while someone tap the textbox?

Comment: Yes i understand that, but someone runs from the Emulator, they may not be knowing that this hyperlink will open another page.. so i need to display the Hand cursor when we Mouse hover.. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP7 is an OS for a phone, so it has no cursor, like lukas said. But, assuming you're using Silverlight, it can be done (if your application will run in Windows/browser). You can change the cursor, and I would point you to [this site](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/08/14/tip-of-the-day-27-how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor.aspx) for example.

But I see you're making a button with a textblock that is underlined. Would [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) not better suit your needs?

Something like:

```
<HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="2" Foreground="#FF057BC3" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" click="HyperlinkButton_Click" Width="400" Margin="-28 -1 0 0" Content="text will be here...." />
```

Comment: Peter, I tried by HyperlinkButton.. I just used the following code.. But it did not display the text which is inside.. So i used Button...                                             <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="2" Foreground="#FF057BC3" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" click="HyperlinkButton_Click" >
                    <TextBlock Width="400" Margin="-28 -1 0 0">
                        <Underline>text will be here....</Underline>
                    </TextBlock>
                </HyperlinkButton>